# C++ (Pop in Array Based Stack) Do we delete the element?

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

Here is some code from a lecture note about STACK using ARRAY implementation.

In the specification:

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
public:
    Stack();
    bool pop (T& stackTop);
    //there is still some other code

private:
    int maxSize;
    int* arr;
    int _size;
}
```

In the implementation:

```
bool Stack<T>::pop(T& stackTop){
    if (isEmpty()){ 
        return false;
    }else{
        --_size;
        stackTop=arr[_size];
        return true;
    }
}
```

and some example of the user program:

```
Stack<int> st;
int k;
st.push(1);st.push(2);st.push(3);//will add element 1 ,2, and 3.
st.pop(k);cout<<"pop"<<k<<endl; //will pop the last element which is 3 and print pop 3
```

I understand that in the pop implementation , we update( reduce by one) the size of the array. BUT we don't seem to erase that element!
So, is the element actually still there, and we just reduce the size so that the top of the array is shifted?
e.g.
my maximum size is 100
in the code I push 1, 2 and 3. now the top is on 3. and the rest 97 elements are still unassigned.
Now I pop (which is the last element that is 3).
When I pop, I just "move" the top to 2. but 3 is actually still there, and the rest 97 elements are still unassigned.
???

Please explain how it works.

Comment: You're storing your elements *by value*. And consider this: your *push* has the same artifact. Ex: if you `int x = 3; st.push(x);` is `x` suddenly no longer expected to be `3` ? Just because your `pop` reduces the stack "top" index doesn't mean the array content it indexed prior disappears (unless *you* choose to overwrite it).

Comment: You're right; the third entry in `arr[]` is still 3.  If you follow the call to `st.pop(k);` with something like `st.push(42);`, the third element will be overwritten.

Comment: Why delete something if you don't have to.  This is just like how your file system works.  It just gets rid of the reference to the file.  The file is still there in "dead" space waiting to be overriden

Comment: @MattOlson So it's actually still there, just the top is shifted by updating the size. So basically it's(the 3) NOW the same as the rest of the 97 elements just that it is assigned to 3, but the "FUNCTION" etc is just the same.

Comment: @mon That's correct.  There's no magic going on behind the scenes; the code does just what it looks like.

Comment: `_size` is a bad name... you are not changing the "size" of the array, but moving the top of the stack to include or not include portions of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Popping an element should remove it from the stack but at the same time return that very same element (whether you delete it or process it further is up to you).

In case you use a static structure such as array for the stack you can simply nullify the content of the cell that represented your stack's top which you have just popped, return that element (if you store by value, then you just return it otherwise return reference) and set the index to the element underneath it as the new top OR create a copy of that array with a smaller size and copy the content that has not been popped there. You can optimize the last method by trying to do popping in a batch that is multiple poppings one after another and then "flush" the stack to a newer smaller one. I personally prefer the first way since a stack is usually considered something with a certain size (=a stack with bounded instead of dynamic capacity).

Removing the element when popping is the way pop in a stack works and if you simply leave the old value there it might for example lead to dumb situation like overwriting an element, that you have popped by a push command but didn't want to overwrite at all. If you do it the proper way you always know that once popped that value can no longer be retrieved (except at the moment of popping it) from that stack because it is no longer there!

Also you can use a single linked list for the implementation and then you can indeed reduce the size of the stack when doing a pop and not just "replace" the popped element with a dummy value or create a new smaller stack and copy the rest there.